# Javascript чтение json

Tags: php, javascript, json, парсер

Есть json в файле:

```
{"image":
    [
    {"imagename":"F", "picture":"f.jpeg",  "size":"300x225"},
    {"imagename":"M", "picture":"m.jpg", "size":"250x250"},
    {"imagename":"S", "picture":"s.jpg", "size":"250x250"},
    {"imagename":"G", "picture":"g.jpg", "size":"250x250"},
    {"imagename":"P", "picture":"p.jpg", "size":"250x250"}
    ]
}
```

В php читаю этот файл и присылаю на страницу:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$outp = file_get_contents("list.json");

echo($outp);
?>
```

Теперь в javascript на странице должен взять данные с того отосланного запроса и вывести на страницу:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "serverJsonRun.php";

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        myFunction(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlhttp.send();

function myFunction(response) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(response);
    var i;
    var out = "<table>";

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        out += "<tr><td>" +
        arr[i].imagename +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].picture +
        "</td><td>" +
        arr[i].size +
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    out += "</table>";

    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

И вот здесь проблема - не могу правильно прочитать arr. Если убрать `{"Image:"` - все читается...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что `arr` это объект, а не массив. Массив будет в `arr.image`

```
var arr = JSON.parse(response).image;
if (!arr) return;
```

Comment: СпасиБо! Теперь все работает.